# Aligning Flex axes so that positive and negative values will be distinguishable

Tags: apache-flex, charts, mxml, axes

I'm trying to set up a simple line chart that contains both positive and negative values, but I'm having trouble setting the correct properties so that the x-axis renders at the middle of the y-axis; all I'm getting right now is the x-axis being at the bottom of the chart.

```
<mx:Stroke id="stroke" color="0x000000" weight="1"/>

<mx:horizonalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{xAxis}" axisStroke="{stroke}"/>
</mx:horizonalAxisRenderers>
<mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
    <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{yAxis}" axisStroke="{stroke}"/>
</mx:verticalAxisRenderers>

<mx:horizontalAxis>
    <mx:LinearAxis id="xAxis"/>
</mx:horizontalAxis>
<mx:verticalAxis>
    <mx:LinearAxis id="yAxis"/>
</mx:verticalAxis>
```

What property/style should I be adding to the axes so that I get the x-axis displayed at the middle of the y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to use the `minimum` and `maximum` properties of the `LinearAxis`. By giving it those hints, it should render the axis in a reasonable location. I did this a long time ago, so it's a little foggy, but I posted a simple example about [rendering negative values on a chart](http://blog.sunild.com/2008/08/inverting-chart-series.html) (source included).

Comment: Thanks for the link! It managed to fix the primary issue I had, but now I'm just fiddling with some other settings. I have a min and max set, but the chart doesn't seem to spread it across the height of its parent component appropriately. But I'll keep working at it!